ASP.NET Core MVC : call Rotativa via Ajax and open in another tab
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and I have to migrate some views to PDF.
I'm using Rotativa and so far it works fine. The PDF opens in a new Tab. I'm running it with
@Html. ActionLink("ExportRotativa", "ExportRotativa", "Controller", null, new { target = "_blank" })

The controller looks like this:
[HttpGet("ExportRotativa")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportRotativa()
{
    DbImpendingMedicareReportViewModel model = await _IfunctionsUtil.ImpendingMedicareElibigibilityReport();
    model.uIElementModel = SessionManagerUtil.GetUIElement(HttpContext.Session);
    return new ViewAsPdf("NewPdf", model);
}

What I need is to call it through Ajax. I need it to be a POST and pass it complex data as parameters. I also need it to have [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] for security reasons.
What I was able to do, according to what I found on a forum, is the following.
<input type="button" hidden="hidden" id="hack" />

function Export() {
    var htmlData;
    var win;
    $.ajax(
       {
           type: "POST",
           headers: {
               "RequestVerificationToken":
                   $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
           },
           url: '@Url.Action("ExportRotativa", "Controller")',
           success: function (data) {
                htmlData = data;
               $("#hack").trigger("click");
           },
           error: OnError
       });
    $("#hack").on("click", function () {
        win = window.open("", "_blank");
        win.document.body.innerHTML = htmlData;
     });
   }

The problem with this is that the PDF shows hieroglyphics, the whole screen broken, instead of the report:

Is there any way to call Rotativa from Ajax with a POST method and that will open it in another tab?
Thanks

Is there any error message? It may be due to the way you're handling the response from the Ajax call, try to create a Blob and then create an object URL to open it in a new tab.

NO error, but I decided to download it instead... It takes less time to download than to open for reports that have more than 200 pages.
Thanks


but I decided to download it instead

Yes, it's a good solution.
And about this question:

The problem with this is that the PDF shows hieroglyphics, the whole screen broken, instead of the report

You can return a Base64 encoded string like:
[HttpPost("ExportRotativa")]
public string ExportRotativa()
{
    DbImpendingMedicareReportViewModel model = await _IfunctionsUtil.ImpendingMedicareElibigibilityReport();
    model.uIElementModel = SessionManagerUtil.GetUIElement(HttpContext.Session);

    var pdfResult = new ViewAsPdf("NewPdf", model);
    var pdfBytes = await pdfResult.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
    string base64EncodedPDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(pdfByteArray);
    return base64EncodedPDF;
}

And
$("#hack").on("click", function () {
    win = window.open("", "_blank");
    win.document.write(
        "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64,
            " + encodeURI(htmlData) + "'></iframe> "
    )
 });

Refer to the apply in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/976115/how-to-get-a-pdf-file-and-open-in-new-tab-in-asp-n
